# How do I setup a command to use the "in word" as an argument

Tags: register, fzf

I would like to set up [vim-fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) to do `git grep`/`rg`/`ag`/*whatever* on the word my cursor is over.  With vim-grepper I was able to do *gs**iw*** for this and it was fantastic.  With fzf I can't seem to figure out how to set that up. (My colleague accomplishes the same task by entering `<CTRL-R><CTRL-W>` at the grep prompt, but I figure this could be done better.)

In general though, for the *in word* commands, how are they set up? (*e.g.* `yiw`, `ciw`, *etc.*)

If I had a function `foo`, how could I send the *in word* as an argument? *i.e.* how would I do:

```
noremap <leader>m :call foo(getreg(*in word*))<cr>
```

For my specific question, I bet I'll be remapping the call to `fzf#vim#grep`, but I thought I'd ask this because I don't even know how to properly refer to the *in word* stuff.

Comment: In case anyone else is curious about using fzf go do a git grep on the current word, I have [the command here](https://github.com/kheaactua/dotfiles/blob/2ec2c6922cb68308fca4f4047cf0396eec1192c1/vimrc#L599)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how could I send the in word as an argument?

```
expand('<cword>')
```

Also see `:h expand()` for a full list of specials.

Comment: nice, I'll give this a try with fzf.  Thanks!